# Simple scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, scroll

I have a simple viewcontroller with labels and text boxes. but to many to fit on one screen, so i would like to add a scrollbar. Do i need a scrollview for that? I only found tutorials about zooming with scrollviews. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a scrollview and set its content size more than the actual size of scrollview. setting content size more than scrollview size will enable scrolling and will show scrollbars...

Comment: how do i change the content size?

Comment: found it already http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW1

Comment: scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(900,900);

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should use UIScrollView. This is good example how to work with scrollView [from Apple developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102)

And [documentation about UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Scroll Vertically
UIView *containerview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 800)];
        [containerview addSubview:your label];
        [containerview addSubview:your textbox];
        ............


UIScrollView *scrv = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        scrv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(containerview.frame.size.width ,containerview.frame.size.height);
        [scrv addSubview:containerview];

[self.view addSubview:scrv];
```